# How can I validate a JSON string against a schema programmatically?

Tags: java, .net, json, validation

Are there simple libraries out there (.NET and Java) that are able to validate a JSON string given a schema definition?

It should work similar to how XML can be validated using XSD.

**EDIT:** I need .NET *and* Java libraries. Thanks to darin for the .NET link!

Comment: The libraries chosen were Json.NET (for .NET) and JsonTools (for Java). I use http://www.json-schema.org/ and http://groups.google.com/group/json-schema/web/json-schema-proposal-working-draft as reference for creating the schemas. You can also check your schema and JSON online here: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/schema.aspx (from the creator of Json.NET)

Comment: I'm betting a lot has changed on this subject since September 2009. What are your thoughts now? Are you using anything for JSON validation (specifically with Java)? Also, @Dejw , how about yourself?

Comment: Well, to tell you the truth, I've moved on to new projects quite soon after I used this validation. If I remember correctly we scrapped the validation in the end. I had to provide a means for validation to appease the higher-ups, who preferred XML. But they were happy without the validation in the end. I don't really see a good reason to add the complexity of validation. Just map your JSON objects to ViewModels or DTOs and do proper parameter checking. Your server-side ViewModels or DTOs can act as a schema definitions and validation all-in-one I believe. That's my take on it these days.

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me.  In the Java world, DTO = serializable POJO, right?  My usage is also simply to meet business requirements and might well just be gold plating.  It seems a number of Java projects in this space have a pretty solid foundation, though.  Namely https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator/ and https://github.com/garycourt/JSV/ .

Comment: Yeah, the DTO would be a serializable POJO. I haven't used Java in quite a while though. I believe you can implement validation during the deserialization, using attributes (annotations in Java?) on your POJO class properties. All these POJO classes do add up though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For .NET you could use [Json.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/Json) which supports [schema validation](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/01/04/json-net-3-5-beta-2-json-schema-validation.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.json.org/java/) You can find some Java classes which might helpful when working with JSON.

When syntax of Your JSON String is incorrect instance of **JSONException** will be thrown - this is the simplest way to check correctness, I think. **JSONTokener** is the class You have to use to parse. It has a constructor which takes **java.lang.String** as a parameter.

**Edit:** Sorry, I misunderstood a little. Probably [JSON Tools](http://jsontools.berlios.de/) is the library You are looking for. It provides [validation using a JSON schema](http://jsontools.berlios.de/articles/documentation/core-1.4-javadoc/jsontools-core-1.4-javadoc/index.html).

Comment: I'm looking for schema validation, not syntax validation. I'll make the question clearer.

Comment: Upvoted, thanks for the link. I'll be using Json.NET and JSON Tools.

No way to accept 2 answers?

Answer (score 2):

www.json-schema.org defines a standard for implementing schemas in JSON.  There is a list of software including validators in many languages here:

http://json-schema.org/implementations.html

Answer (score 1):

I've used NJsonSchema for .NET library recently for validation against a schema and it worked perfectly for me, even for complex schemes with definitions in several files:

https://github.com/NJsonSchema/NJsonSchema

> NJsonSchema is a .NET library to read, generate and validate JSON Schema draft v4 schemas. The library can read a schema from a file or string and validate JSON data against it. A schema can also be generated from an existing .NET class. With the code generation APIs you can generate C# and TypeScript classes or interfaces from a schema.

It allows not only validate against schema, but also to generate schema files from existing classes. The advantage is that it is an open source and the communication with the author of the project was very quick and good in case of my questions.

It can be a good choice for someone looking for a free solution for validation.